# Full Calendar - Days grouped on left and times across top week view?

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, fullcalendar

Is it possible to get a full calendar view with the days on the left for the week and the times across the top?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing view which does this (or can be configured to to this) in fullCalendar at the time of writing, no.

If you want to attempt to create this, you would need to create a custom view yourself using JavaScript - latest documentation (for v5 at the time of writing) is here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js

This appears not to be a simple process - there is a lot to think about, and of course you are likely to need to ensure the view stays compatible with future updates to the core fullCalendar code. One possible way to approach it to begin with might be to look at the code of one of the existing views in the fullCalendar source code (available from their GitHub repo) and use that as a starting point.